# ORM and php to filter out dates in database

Tags: php, mysql, orm

If I write this ORM query in my php file I get back all of the items with the date of "2000-01-01"  but how do I get all of the dates back that are "2000-01-01" and above?  I've tried but doesn't work...

Note: all of the dates in the database are in this format: yyyy-mm-dd

```
$results = ORM::for_table('my_table')
            ->where('slug', "slug_name")
            ->where('date', 'date'>="2000-01-01")
            ->find_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its `idiorm`

http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html#less-than-greater-than-where-lt-where-gt-where-lte-where-gte

And from the doc the query builder should be as

```
$results = ORM::for_table('my_table')
            ->where('slug', "slug_name")
            ->where_gte('date', "2000-01-01")
            ->find_array();
```